# connect web application to multiple windows odbc databases

Tags: php, windows, soap, remote-access

I have a web-based application written in PHP that needs to communicate with numerous windows pc's or network servers that have an odbc compliant database on them. Specifically, I need to read/write from/to each odbc database from the web-based application. What is best way to do this? Use sockets, HTTP Listener, etc? Also, can you point me to resources to help me get started? Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Are all the computers available from the server (ex:lan)?

Answer (score 0):

Have many ways to skin that cat.

By the way you can keep in your mind 2 things: in your project some conections will need be persitent and anothers connections no.

It's a big mistake generalize persistent db connections by default, at first look it's not obvius, but persistent connections will not close after execution of your php script, so it's be managed and be keeped to future re-use.

If you are starting your project a nice option are PDO with ODBC.

http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-odbc.connection.php